# Bash. How to convert UTF-8 to hex encode?

Tags: string, bash, utf-8, hex

I have got one variable with string of UTF-8 text. I want to get string like `\xAA\xBB\xCC` or, it seems to be encoded as `\Uxxxxxxxx` or some such... How can I to realize it?

Comment: Actual sample strings and desired results would be useful.

Comment: For example: `12345 =\n= me + Дварфы` <=> `\U31\U32\U33\U34\U35\U20\U3d\Ua\U3d\U20\U6d\U65\U20\U2b\U20\U414\U432\U430\U440\U444\U44b`

Comment: That should go in the question proper, not a comment, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I could to do it with Python3 (.7):

```
def stou(x):
    s = ''
    for i in x:
        s = s + '\\U' + hex(ord(i))[2:]
    return s
```

But I'd like to resolve it by native bash methods and (or) by standard, almost native utils of Linux, like `base64` or `find`. I'm just trying to create file server and in usual format I have problems with space-chars. So I try to find some another method to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```sh
$ echo -ne "12345 =\n= me + Дварфы" | perl -0777 -CS -nE 'say map { sprintf "\\U%x", $_ } unpack "U*"'
\U31\U32\U33\U34\U35\U20\U3d\Ua\U3d\U20\U6d\U65\U20\U2b\U20\U414\U432\U430\U440\U444\U44b
```

Basically, reads all of its standard input as one UTF-8 encoded chunk, converts each codepoint to a number, and prints them out in base 16 with a leading `\U` before each one.